# C# timer function won't allow for int values? Requests System.CompontentModel.IContainer?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created the delay function below with the intention of creating a delay within the certain bounds of my "min" and "max" inputs.

```
    private void delay(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int timerLength = rnd.Next(min, max);
        Timer timer = new Timer(timerLength);
        timer.Start();
    }
```

I get an error in the line

```
Timer timer = new Timer(timerLength);
```

As the compiler cannot convert timer Length from an int to a "System.ComponentModel.IContainer". I've tried to convert the input values to IContainers but with no success, as the random function only allows int values.

Is there a workaround to this at all, so that the timer function can take an int? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13f3s8ea(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `Timer` constructor enables you to associate a `Timer` with any
>   `Container` object. By associating the `Timer` like this, you hand over
>   control of the lifetime of the `Timer` to the `Container`. This can be
>   useful if you use a number of components in your application and want
>   to dispose of all of them simultaneously. For example, if you
>   associate a `ToolTip`, an `ImageList`, and a `Timer` with a `Container`,
>   calling Dispose on the Container will force disposal of all of these
>   components as well.

So, if I understand you right, you are trying to set the interval for your `Timer`. In that case you need to use the 'Interval` property:

```
private void delay(int min, int max)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int timerLength = rnd.Next(min, max);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = timerLength; // the value in milliseconds.
    timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int timerLength = rnd.Next(min, max);
Timer timer = new Timer(); //changed
Timer.Interval=timerLength; // added line
timer.Start();
```

Edit: fixed formatting